# c# openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory from string

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Am pretty new to C# and i need some help on a project i make.
I making an application we need. The application is to search our DB2 for the case number given on textbox by user. This is working fine i retrieve all data i need just fine. Now i want to click a button and open file dialog and user can select one of the files that exists in a folder on our win server under the folder that exists and named with the case number given in text box. So the initial directory should be dynamically changed according to the value in the textbox.

On my first attempt i declared the case number on a

```
string public String Gazm = "155465";
```

then i called initial directory

```
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = $@"\\apollo\zm\{Gazm}";
```

and worked fine. Dialogue opened on `\\apollo\zm\155465\` and i could choose the files in the folder. I was was happy and i thought that that was easy and that i now have only to change the value of Gazm variable to the one given by user and i will do that easy with:

```
Gazm = textBox2.Text;
```

.So i did all happy and when i clicked the button the dialogue opened in the `\\apollo\zm\` and not at the `\\apollo\zm\Gazm\` where `Gazm = textbox.text`.

I thought there is something wrong with the string construction so what i tried next is that i made a `String foldername = $@"\\apollo\zm\";` and `public string fld = "";` . then i edit in button_click where the case number from user is captured the `string fld = foldername + azm;` and i send this result to be displayed in a textbox to check if the result is the desired.

The result in the textbox was the desired path to the case's number folder but the openfiledialogue will still open on the `\\apollo\zm\` where then path in the textbox was the `\\apollo\zm\155465\` where 155465 was the case number i typed in the textbox.

As i told you am new in C# and i dont know if what am doing is possible.
Please be kind with noob ;)

i will paste my code now which is only the code that reffers to the openfile dialogue. I made a new solution just for that part so i can do my tests on test solution rather than my main project.
Thank you for any help .

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.Tab;

namespace AutoZhm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String Gazm = "";
        String filename = "";
        String foldername = $@"\\apollo\zm\";
        public string fld = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String Gazm = textBox1.Text;
            string fld = foldername + azm;
            textBox97.Text = fld;
        }

        private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
             openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = fld;
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Browse Text Files";
            openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
            openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
            openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
            openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox97.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                filename = textBox97.Text;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your post a little better. On mobile it's a wall of text which I can't even begin to read. On scanning the text I don't see a question mark... Is there a question in there?

Comment: am also noob on question posting as till now i was finding solutions allready posted. My problem was solved thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `fld` variables defined twice, once in your class and once within your `button1_Click` method. I suspect that this is causing you trouble.

The `fld` variable within the `button1_Click` is defined as a local variable. Meaning that it only exists within that method. The `fld` variable defined in your class is not updated by this method as a result, in fact in the code you've shown it well never change from an empty string.

You can easily fix this by removing the type declaration (`string fld = [..]`  to `fld = [..]`) within the button1_Click method. That will cause the code to use the class defined variable (which the `button4_Click_1` can also access).

---

Now, as you want an adjustment of the input in your TextBox to determine the initial directory, you'll need to set `openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory` to the current value `textBox97.Text`.